# So i modified my sudoer file and now sudo hangs and I can't change it back

Tags: mac, unix, sudo

I was having fun messing around in terminal when suddenly, I messed up my sudoers file in /etc/. Now the sudo command hangs and I am not able to change it back. I would rather not reset my computer completely. Is there any way to restore the sudoers file back to defaults? (I'm on mac osx 10.12.6). Thanks

Comment: In case you don't know how to "have fun" in a relatively safe way: `man 8 visudo`. For future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can [start your Mac in single user mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) and from there, revert the changes you've made.

**Edit**: You may find [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37764/i-accidentally-deleted-the-sudoers-file-on-mac-os-x-is-there-any-way-to-recover) the original sudoers file, or at least a reference to understand what went wrong in your edition.

Remember to use visudo to check the syntax of your sudoers file.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Edited my answer with a reference to the original file.